# Immediately mark messages as read when opened in preview pane

Tags: gmail

I'm using the [**preview pane**](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9499937?hl=en) in gmail. When I click multiple messages in a row, none of them are marked as read.

I'd like them to be marked as read immediately.

[image: Gmail Preview Pane Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting specifically for this Under General > Mark a conversation as read:

[image: Settings > General > Preview Pane]

You can also [double click to mark as read](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/24443516/double-click-to-mark-message-as-read?hl=en)